# Game Design: handling different game types?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm curious if there is a good strategy for handling various game types inside a game that run off the same main game loop? In other words, I have a game with three different game types. There are only a few minor differences between each type, so they currently run using the same loop/classes. One is a 'how many X's can you get before time runs out', another is 'how long does it take you to capture 10 X's', and the last is a 'practice/ infinite time' game type. Right now my strategy is to run an if, then, else check at all differentiating parts of the game and perform the appropriate logic for each game type.

```
if (gameType == INFINITE)
{...}
else if (gameType == TIMED)
{...}
else
{...}
```

This seems horribly wrong to me, and also inefficient. I don't want to bog down the CPU with all these unnecessary checks when it seems like I could do this check once and proceed forward. I also do not want to copy-paste all of my classes to only make minor changes in each. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle that is to create a screen manager system. This essentially means that you have an abstract class with update and draw operations. Each game (screen) you have then inherits from this, allowing each to have its own update/draw behavior. Ultimately you need to have an if-else or switch statement to decide which to draw/update. One way to minimize this is to keep track of the current "screen" using a variable of your abstract type, you can then polymorphically assign whichever screen needs to be update/drawn to that variable. Then when you call update or draw on the current screen you don't need to know it's concrete type.

There are lots of examples out there, a decent XNA one can be found at:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

The idea is completely transferable. Most use this system to add menu screens and things, but there is no reason it couldn't be used for your purpose.

Comment: Oh boy. This would require a major, major refactoring of my code.

Comment: ah ... how i truly miss a 'truly' abstract class in objective-C. However, i agree that that would be the way to go : an abstract controller that has 3 (or N) implementations, and a factory to instantiate the appropriate one. Protocols would do too :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is an instance where I just don't have time to refactor. Also, I'm using the Cocos2D engine which right out of the gate makes MVC design patterns a bit tricky.

Comment: lol, i understand ... besto luck with the ifs and switches then !

Comment: Will this seriously damper performance, say, if I'm doing that check every update in ~ 4 different places?

Comment: well, when it comes to performance, only one way to know for sure, is to measure it - on devices. I generally find that a few ifs are a drop in the proverbial bucket with cocos2d, especially considering the cost of graphic rendering. But once again, measure measure measure. And only optimize if there is something.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be problematic in initial tests. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Clever Just to let you know, you shouldn't really be checking every frame. You should assign whatever game it is to the current game and only update/draw it, I wouldn't think that would happen too often so your performance should barely change. Check out the code at the link i posted to see the full implementation details. Glad this helped you :)

Comment: cocos2d+MVC? KoboldTouch ;)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : hehehe, never to miss such a good opportunity. Actually, i had developed my own patterns before i started reading this forum. So yes, it is not only possible, but a 'life saver' when the game designer changes his mind like he changes his shirt. I'll give your framework a shake next game around.

Comment: @ChrisMcCabe the only problem is that the way I have everything setup (poorly), this would be a very difficult thing to do. I have a Menu, where the player decides on the type. I then launch a GameScene with that type, and inform all necessary classes of the type. The Logic Manager class handles most of the heavy lifting, but some of the if/then game type checks occur outside of the logic loop (like in the clock/timer).

Comment: @Clever Ooo that's a nasty bit of coupling there

Comment: Tell me about it >.>. Any other suggestions? I could copy-paste a large amount of code, I suppose. It might set my soul on fire, but I could do it. Something like -- LogicManagerRace, LogicManagerTime, LogicManagerInfinite...

Comment: @Clever If what you have at the minute works for you and it will cause you a lot of headaches to redesign then I would take this as a lesson learned and avoid the problem in the future. With the kind of tight coupling you're describing almost any design pattern that solves your problem will require quite a bit of refactoring. Best of luck!